# Client Websocket SSL -- Connect to specific IP address

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, networking, websocket

Let's say there is a website called https://example.com. A DNS lookup on the domain returns the following A records:

```
1.1.1.1 A example.com
1.1.1.2 A example.com
1.1.1.3 A example.com
1.1.1.4 A example.com
```

Each one of these addresses has the SSL certificate for example.com and is running a websocket server on port 443.

A client can connect to one of the servers using something like

```
var wss = new WebSocket("wss://example.com");
```

This will connect the client to a server based on DNS Round Robin: the client has no control over what server she connects to.

My question is the following:

**How can a client connect to a specific address without having certificate issues?**

For example, if the client knows that she wishes to connect to 1.1.1.4 and tries to connect with

```
var wss = new WebSocket("wss://1.1.1.4");
```

she will encounter an ssl error since the server cannot have the individual address as an alternative name in its certificate.

**Is it possible to specify the hostname along with an individual address when making the connection**; something like

```
var wss = new WebSocket("wss://example.com?ip=1.1.1.4");
```

I believe you can do this using CURL with something like `curl https:// DOMAIN.TLD --resolve 'DOMAIN.TLD:443:IP_ADDRESS'`

Comment: I don't know. But it sounds fishy. Why would you want to do this? This round robin config is there for a reason. If it's your sever, you could make a separate DNS entry that refers to that specific address, and make the server allow that address as well. If it's not your server, don't do this.

Comment: "Why would you want to do this?" If you have a dynamic environment where you are spinning servers up and down and DNS is too slow. The client queries the server for the current available addresses and needs to connect to a specific one. Or if you are trying to scale a chat service -- client asks the server what address their friend is on, server says the specific address, and the client needs to connect to that specific address. Maybe I'm approaching the problem strangely -- is there a more common way to do this?

Comment: REF: _Is it possible to specify the hostname along with an individual address when making the connection; something like..._. -- no this is only interpreted once it has arrived at the host. BUT, each host could definitely redirect based upon protocol. Pseudo: `if(protocol is wss && p) forward to wss://p`

Comment: "Maybe I'm approaching the problem strangely". For your chat service example, you can either use subdomains (and the first user will send the link of this subdomain to his friend), or location based DNS. I agree this is not your real question.

Comment: To achieve your goal, you would need your WS client to be able to give some parameters to the underlying software (browser ?), especially the SNI when connecting with TLS. With openssl, it looks like : openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect 1.1.1.2 . With the browsers implementations (JavaScript) it seems you can't , although it's theoritically possible with other implementations (Java, perl,..)

Comment: @EugèneAdell "With the browsers implementations (JavaScript) it seems you can't " I was afraid that this was the case -- do you have a source for this?

Comment: Both the Websocket API and RFC 6455 don't talk at all about accessing the underlying client to set parameters. According to this interesting post, it's even not possible with Firefox to access so low level things : https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/can-firefox-add-ons-access-information-in-the-ssl-tls-handshake/4979

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you: [Is Round-Robin DNS “good enough” for load balancing static content?](https://serverfault.com/questions/101053/is-round-robin-dns-good-enough-for-load-balancing-static-content)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the certificate issue, request a domain name instead of an IP. I suggest this :

> ```
> 1.1.1.1 A example.com
> 1.1.1.2 A example.com
> 1.1.1.3 A example.com
> 1.1.1.4 A example.com
> 1.1.1.1 A a.example.com
> 1.1.1.2 A b.example.com
> 1.1.1.3 A c.example.com
> 1.1.1.4 A d.example.com
> ```

and one single SAN certificate for all of the 5 domains (example.com + [a-d].example.com)
You can test any of [a-d].example.com individually, or example.com, all will respond with the same certificate and there's no issue I think.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer Eugene. This is technically an answer to the question as asked, but I was wondering if you had any suggestions that met the criteria I outlined in the comment section: "dynamic environment where you are spinning servers up and down and DNS is too slow". AFAIK this answer would not work well for that scenario since new servers would have to create new certs and update the DNS -- is that correct? Perhaps this is a scenario where a wildcard certificate might make sense?

Comment: Yes, the wildcard certificate *.example.com will allow to add/remove servers from your hosting, but you still need DNS adding/removing of individual servers (e.example.com and so on). When we are setting up solutions around DNS for disaster recovery, we use solutions that monitor each server and add/remove DNS entries for us in their DNS answers. This is something that you probably don't have, so you can't be completely dynamic. And you need the shortest DNS TTL possible.

Comment: I'm facing this exact scenario (DNS stuff too) and I'm unsure on how to go about implementing a Wildcard certificate on the subdomains while making use of an EV SSL certificate add-on (from DigiCert) on the primary domain (https://example.com), all while making WSS within the domain(s) "work". Our use case requires clients to WSS to both the primary domain (wss://example.com/websocket/loginserver) AND the subdomains (wss://a.example.com/websocket/gameserver). If I put the Wildcard cert on the subdomains and the EV SSL add-on cert on the primary domain, will WSS "work" for my use-case?

Comment: @mcw DigiCert sells Multi-domain certificates with EV (example : qz.com) and if you look at DigiCert products, they say there is Wildcard option for the multi-domain certificates. This means that maybe one single certificate would be enough for both wildcard and EV, but you need to check with them of course.

Comment: I went for the Wildcard option because it can support infinite subdomains upon certificate creation (correct me if I'm wrong), which will scale nicely. Multi-domain certs require defining each subdomain upon certificate creation, which is TBD at runtime depending on sever load. I guess what I'm asking is, if the primary domain is setup with an EV SSL certificate and subdomains are using the wildcard certificate, can WSS connect to any subdomain (after visiting the page with its primary domain certificate)? Would be nice to have the EV seal and subdomains working with this configuration.

Comment: According to DigiCert, Wildcard certs will cover the primary domain as well as subdomains (https://www.digicert.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates/) .. so I guess this means WSS would for sure work if the Wildcard cert was on the primary domain in addition to the subdomains - but I'm interested in making the primary domain use EV SSL while also having a Wildcard on scaleable subdomains that support WSS on the primary domain as well as all subdomains.

Comment: I suppose this would work as you want it, with 2 certificates : 1 EV on the main domain, and a wild-card for the subdomains. But I didn't test myself, and you should try with self-signed certificates, and with round-robin DNS as you also want. With one single certificate from DigiCert, if I read well, it is possible to buy a multi-domain with these 2 options : EV + wildcard. This way, you have infinite subdomains. But before buying anything, check with them.

Comment: Will do .. I appreciate the thoughts and suggestions. I'll report back with my findings after trying some things.

Comment: the feedbacks are highly appreciated, very few are coming back unluckily.

Comment: The ideal solution worked. 1 EV cert on the primary domain and 1 Wildcard for the subdomains with WSS connections working to both endpoints from the primary domain. Note that I had to purchase the EV add-on together with Wildcard to make this work (our original EV SSL certificate did not work with the Wildcards, possible messed something up though) .. so when purchasing Wildcard and adding the EV addon those certificates are compatible (I guess?, not really sure). A setup using only Wildcard for the primary and subdomains also worked with WSS, but then the EV seal was lost, as expected.